# Microsoft Graph OneNote API returns 504 Gateway Timeout error when requesting sections

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I have an application for OneNote users. Some users are receiving a "504 Gateway Timeout" error when requesting sections from notebook: `/notebooks/{ID}/sections`.

Request/response example:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks/{ID}/sections`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-07-04T06:59:23",
            "request-id": "aa623923-df7a-48e1-96c1-d2026f862a2b",
            "client-request-id": "aa623923-df7a-48e1-96c1-d2026f862a2b"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix it and get sections?

Additionally, before June 28th 2023, users did not experience this error, but now they do.